# how to store the result of a jdbc query as a relation to use it in the next query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In JDBC, I want to execute a MySQL query and store its result **as a relation** to using it in the next query, for that I am doing something like this:

```
public static void getaData() throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase","xyz","abc@123");
        PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement("select * from table1 join table2 using(table2_id)");
        ResultSet result1 = statement1.executeQuery();

        PreparedStatement statement2 = connection.prepareStatement("select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as full_name,  party_name, head, symbol from ("+result1+") as subTable");                       
        ResultSet result2 = statement2.executeQuery();

        System.out.printf("%-30s%-30s%-30s%-30s\n\n", "full_name", "party_name", "head", "symbol");
        while(result2.next())
            System.out.printf( "%-30s%-30s%-30s%-30s\n", result2.getString(0), result2.getString(1), result2.getString(2), result2.getString(3) );

    }
```

but this is throwing exception that is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@60d5ad52) as subTable' at line 1
```

So please how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is wrong. you can't use parenthesis near FROM like you have done. It should be either,

```
from "+result1+"
```

or

```
from ("+result+" as subtable)
```

above change will fix your problem.

Comment: Found the error. You should give a table name as a string instead of an object.result1 is not a string

Comment: String result = result1.toString();
still same error after doing this

Comment: @Raees, result1 is a ResultSet object. by invoking the toString() you can't expect it to be a table name.

Comment: then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need statement1 or result1.

```
String subTable = "select * from table1 join table2 using(table2_id)";
PreparedStatement statement2 = connection.prepareStatement("select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as full_name,  party_name, head, symbol from ("+subTable+") as subTable");
```